# Problems with bulk mailing phpmailer using smtp

Tags: php, smtp

I have used php mailer in my site. It runs well. But if i have around 1000s of emails in my database, it  gets delayed to deliver the mails. It sends the mail one by one. Is there anyway to send bulk emails using smtp without any delay?

Comment: Which MTA (email/SMTP) server software do you use?

Comment: i am using phpmailer. | Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class |

| Version: 5.0.0 |  https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer       Is there anyway to send mails at a bulk just liek a batch or something by using phpmailer or something?

Comment: **suggestion** : You are sending more than 100 people then you need to set cron which is read data from the database and set status as well.